# Why time duration needs double dot for Prometheus but not for Victoria metrics

Tags: prometheus, promql, victoriametrics

I am using Prometheus for short time period queries (few hours) and VictoriaMetrics for long term (months). I have metric from Loki, that shows logs bytes over time for last 1 minute - metric name `logs_bytes_over_time_1m`.

Metric `logs_bytes_over_time_1m` has 4 labels:

- **hostname** - name of node it is running on in swarm
- **replica** - number of replica
- **service** - service name
- **stack** - stack where service belongs to (in Docker Swarm)

I wanted to have average value for one hour so I build this query:

```
avg_over_time(sum by (service) (logs_bytes_over_time_1m{service="myapp"})[1h])
```

- **sum over service** - I need only sum over service label and sum it up because otherwise, there can be multiple series differs by hostname (or in some cases filename they are scraped from). This result show only one series with label service.
- **avg_over_time** - count average over time, in my case `1h`

This works perfectly with VictoriaMetrics in Grafana but when I run this query in over Prometheus datasource I receive the error:

```
bad_data: 1:88: parse error: ranges only allowed for vector selectors
```

Once I add doulbe dot `:` in time duration, it works for Prometheus datasource:

```
avg_over_time(sum by (service) (logs_bytes_over_time_1m{service="myapp"})[1h:])
```

But when I remove sum subquery:

```
avg_over_time(logs_bytes_over_time_1m{service="myapp"}[1h])
```

The query works for both Prometheus and VictoriaMetrics.

The difference I see is that with `sum by` the result series has only one label - `service`. If I group it by service and stack:

```
avg_over_time(sum by (service, stack) (logs_bytes_over_time_1m{service="myapp"})[1h])
```

It works fine with VictoriaMetrics and Prometheus datasource.

What is the reason, the query is different? I always using time duration in Prometheus alerts without double dot.

Answer (score 1):

The [avg_over_time](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#avg_over_time) is a [rollup function](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#rollup-functions). This function calculates results over raw samples on some interval, which starts in the past and ends at the current time. This interval is usually named `lookbehind window`. For example, `avg_over_time(m[1h])` calculates the average value over raw samples for time series `m` on the interval `(t-1h ... t]`, where `t` is the current time. If `m` returns multiple time series, then the rollup function calculates results individually per each time series.

Rollup functions expect [time series selector](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#time-series-selectors) with lookbehind window in square brackets as an argument. If something other is passed to rollup function, then the following cases are possible:

- Prometheus returns `expected type range vector in call to function "...", got instant vector` if [subquery](https://prometheus.io/blog/2019/01/28/subquery-support/) isn't called explicitly. For example, such an error is returned in the following cases `avg_over_time(m)` or `avg_over_time(sum(m))`.
- Prometheus returns `ranges only allowed for vector selectors` if the colon with optional step is missing in [subquery](https://prometheus.io/blog/2019/01/28/subquery-support/)'s square brackets. For example, such an error is returned in `avg_over_time(sum(m)[1h])`.
- [Subquery execution](https://prometheus.io/blog/2019/01/28/subquery-support/). For example, `avg_over_time(sum(m)[1h:])` would calculate the `sum(m)` per each point on the graph and then calculate the average over these points with one hour lookbehind window.

VictoriaMetrics doesn't return errors in these cases, since it automatically performs the needed conversions as [documented here](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#implicit-query-conversions):

- `avg_over_time(m)` is automatically converted to the equivalent of `avg_over_time(m[$__interval])`, where `$__interval` is the interval between adjacent points on the graph in Grafana.
- `avg_over_time(sum(m))` is automatically converted into `avg_over_time(sum(default_rollup(m[$__interval]))[$__interval:$__interval])`
- `avg_over_time(sum(m)[1h])` and `avg_over_time(sum(m)[1h:])` are automatically converted into the same query - `avg_over_time(sum(default_rollup(m[$__interval]))[1h:$__interval])`.